# How can an iOS app have more crashes than sessions?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, analytics

On https://analytics.itunes.apple.com, for one of the many apps of our company, I see this:

```
Period: 30 days
Opt-in rate: 31%
Impressions | App Units | Opt-in Sessions | Opt-in Crashes
      3,089 |        27 |              17 |             42
```

Other info: iOS 8+.

**How can it have more crashes than sessions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a Medium article ([Apple App Analytics 101 (updated)](https://medium.com/appmanager/apple-app-analytics-101-93f399b41ff4)):

> #### Sessions
>
> The number of times the app has been used for at least two seconds. If the app is in the background and is later used again, that counts as another session.

Which means that if the crashes occur within the first two seconds of the app launch, it won't register as a session.